# Graph combining HorizontalBarChart & CubicLineChart?

Tags: ios-charts

Is it possible to draw a graph combining a HorizontalBarChart with a CubicLineChart with iOS-charts? The CubicLineChart would be drawn from top to bottom, following the horizontal bars rather than left to right.

If not, can anyone recommend a graph library that would support this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, No. But technically, you could, but you need to do a lot of decent study on the framework and rewrite a bunch of methods to get it work.

Check out how combined chart is carried out, and make sure you understand how the ChartTransformer get setup and work. Then you are good to go.

The other way is, use vertical bar chart and normal line chart to get what you want, like a combined chart, and rotate it 90 degree, and customize the axis labels maybe easier for you?

BTW, you need to know that chart is making data easy to understand, I'm not sure would a chart like you said make it easier?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and design options @Wingzero. I'll have a look at the framework and see if I feel confident to modify it. If so, I'll make sure to submit it as possible addition to iOS-Chart.  
<br/>
As for the clarity of the data, I'm discussing it with our UI designer right now ;) But as we're using portrait mode in all the rest of the app and the data we want display is based on time through the day so 00:00 at the top till midnight at the bottom in 2hrs increment on the x axis on the hight of the screen in portrait mode, does makes sense.

Comment: I guess people does not get used to read lines from top to bottom? It's ok you want to do this, make sure you have UE produces some examples if the charts are good to your customers

Comment: btw, we are using normal bars and lines even in portrait mode. users can zoom and scroll the chart for more details